# Escape special characters in java

Tags: java

I have a text file having `|` (pipe) as the separator. If I am reading a column and the column itself also contains `|` then it while separating another column is created.

Example :

```
name|date|age
zzz|20-03-22|23
"xx|zz"|23-23-33|32
```

How can I escape the character within the double quotes `""`
how to escape the regular expression used in the split, so that it works for user-specified delimiters
i have tried 
 String[] cols = line.split("\|");
                System.out.println("lets see column only=="+cols[1]);

Comment: Is it always the case that this column will itself contain pipes? Will it always contain the same number of pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSV parser like OpenCSV ou Commons CSV

- http://opencsv.sourceforge.net
- http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv

Answer (score 3):

> ***How can I escape the character within the double quotes ""***

Here's one approach:

```
String str = "\"xx|zz\"|23-23-33|32";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"").matcher(str);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().replace("|", "\\\\|"));

m.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb);  // prints "xx\|zz"|23-23-33|32
```

---

In order to get the columns back you'd do something like this:

```
String str = "\"xx\\|zz\"|23-23-33|32";
String[] cols = str.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|");

for (String col : cols)
    System.out.println(col.replace("\\|", "|"));
```

---

**Regarding your edit:**

> ***how to escape the regular expression used in the split, so that it works for user-specified delimiters***

You should use `Pattern.quote` on the string you want to split on:

```
String[] cols = line.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter));
```

This will ensure that the split works as intended even if `delimiter` contains special regex-symbols such as `.` or `|`.

Comment: i have tried String[] cols = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
but when i print it, the | within the double quotes is considered and a seperate column is created
 System.out.println("lets see column only=="+cols[1]);
gives me zz" even though it should be 23-23-33 in string "xx|zz"|23-23-33|32

Comment: Then escape the `|` characters according to my first snippet, and use my second snippet to extract the columns.

Comment: hii your 1st snippet will only escape | characters within double quotes if i have intrepreted it correctly but if i have to escape any other characters say a ',' then il have to specify another regex isnt it .. is there a more generic solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with its unicode sequence (prior to delimiting with pipe)

But what you should do is adjust your parser to take that into account, rather than changing the files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to parse it

```
    String str = "zzz|20-03-22|23 \"xx|zz\"|23-23-33|32";
    String regex = "(?<=^|\\|)(([^\"]*?)|([^\"]+\"[^\"]+\".*?))(?=\\||$)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

**Output**:

```
zzz
20-03-22
23 "xx|zz"
23-23-33
32
```